# Is this a correct huffman tree for the following distributions of characters?

Tags: tree, huffman-code

```
letter frequency
a 5
b 6
c 5
d 6
e 11
f 13
g 23
h 25
i 26
j 46
```

Here is what I get, correct me if I'm wrong: a and c both 5, to get node 10, b and d both 6 to get 12, combine to get 22, e and f on other subtree to get 24, the 2 smallest nodes are now g and 22 from a c and b d, combine for 45 on first subtree, h combines with e and f on 2nd subtree to get 49, i on first subtree to get 71, and finally j on 2nd subtree to get 95, parent node is 166.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to pick the two lowest total frequencies at each step. At your third step you combined a 10 and a 12 when you should have combined a 10 and an 11.

Try again.